# C#.Net can't see user control in the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to use my user control manually in the code, but i can't see the user control class.

This is my User Control:

View top:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CustomerTable.ascx.cs"
    Inherits="Controls_CustomerTable" ClassName="CustomerTable" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/DynamicList.ascx" TagName="Control" TagPrefix="DynamicList" %>
```

Code:

```
/// <summary>
/// customer presantation
/// </summary>
public partial class Controls_CustomerTable : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The customer for this control
    /// </summary>
    private Customer customer;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Getter and setter for the customer
    /// </summary>
    private Customer Customer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.customer;
        }
        set
        {
            this.customer = value;
            showCustomer();
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Show the customer details
    /// </summary>
    private void showCustomer()
    {
        //set customer details
        customerName.InnerText = customer.name;
        description.InnerText = customer.shortDescription;
        clientIntrest.List = customer.interstedParties;
        clientUsers.List = customer.users;
    }
}
```

This is in my Page:

View top:

Code:
[image]

As you can see it doesn't get recognized...

Comment: Incorrect control data type, according to your code it should be Controls_CustomerTable, not CustomerTable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note how you define your class:

```
public partial class Controls_CustomerTable
```

And how you try to use it:

```
CustomerTable table
```

Class names can't be kind of close, they have to be exact.  You'll need to reference the class by its whole name:

```
Controls_CustomerTable table
```

Comment: I tried a new user control and i have the same problem again.. names are fine.. what else can go wrong ?

Comment: @AsafNevo: Did you include the namespace?  If it's in a different namespace you'd either need a `using` directive at the top of the file or you'd need to fully-qualify the class name.

Comment: its a web site not application.. i dont have name spaces